# Issue using RegEx with Linux find

Tags: regex, linux

I'm writing a script to find and list files on my video drive that aren't already .mkv format, as well as listing any multi-episode files so that I can eventually convert and split these files properly.

Examples of files that should match:

```
Path/to/FilE332.1/Series Title/Season 01/Series - S01E03 - Episode Name Bluray-2160p.mkv
/Series - S01E103 - Episode Name WEBDL-1080p.mkv
```

Examples of files that shouldn't match:

```
Path/to/FilE332.1/Series Title/Season 01/Series - S01E04E05 - Episode Name SDTV.mkv
/Series - S01E04E05 - Episode Name SDTV.mkv
```

Here's the command I came up with:

```
find /path/to/files -type f ! -regex ".*- S\d{2}E(?:\d{3}|\d{2}) -.*\.mkv"
```

This regex seems to be working properly when tested on regex101's website, so I'm pretty confident that the regex string is correct: https://regex101.com/r/iyUbh6/1

I've tried adding the -regextype flag to no avail:

```
find /path/to/files -type f ! -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*- S\d{2}E(?:\d{3}|\d{2}) -.*\.mkv"
find /path/to/files -type f ! -regextype posix-basic -regex ".*- S\d{2}E(?:\d{3}|\d{2}) -.*\.mkv"
find /path/to/files -type f ! -regextype egrep -regex ".*- S\d{2}E(?:\d{3}|\d{2}) -.*\.mkv"
```

I also read some stuff about \d not working properly, so I tried changing it to [[:digit:]]. That didn't work either.

```
find /path/to/files -type f ! -regextype posix-basic -regex ".*- S[[:digit:]]{2}E(?:[[:digit:]]{3}|[[:digit:]]{2}) -.*\.mkv"
find /path/to/files -type f ! -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*- S[[:digit:]]{2}E([[:digit:]]{3}|[[:digit:]]{2}) -.*\.mkv"
```

I don't really know where to go from here, so hopefully someone with more experience has some insight on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The following assumes you're using GNU find, which since you mention Linux, is a safe bet.

The [default regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/findutils_002ddefault-regular-expression-syntax.html) does not understand `\d` (Instead you'd use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`). Alternation is `\|`. I don't think it supports repetition ranges; they're [not documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/findutils_002ddefault-regular-expression-syntax.html). POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax also doesn't understand `\d`, or alternation (though some GNU implementations do as an extension using `\|`), and requires many other things like groups and repetition ranges to be escaped. And none of the supported flavors supports non-capturing grouping (`(?:...)`).

Since your alternating group tests for either two or three digits, it can be turned into a single range when using one of the RE flavors that supports them.

So, something like:

```
find /path/to/files -regextype posix-extended -type f ! -regex ".*- S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2,3} -.*\.mkv"
```

is probably the cleanest approach.

Comment: Your very last one looks like it should work, btw. Maybe it's the placement of the `-regextype` option after the `!` that's breaking it?

Answer (score 0):

I just pipe `find` to `grep -v` to do the filtering out:

```
find path -type f | grep -v \.mkv
```